# Any inherently ambiguous language with algebraic counting generating function?

Tags: power-series, formal-languages, automata

Any inherently ambiguous language with algebraic counting generating function?

$f(x)=\sum_1^{\infty}a_ix^i$,is counting generating function for $L$, a language,where $a_i$ is the number of words of $L$ with length $i$. If there is  $P(f(x),x) =0$ over fields $\mathbb{Q}$, $f(x)$ is algebraic.

Comment: What does an algebraic counting generating function mean?  That it is a rational function of $x$?  Please modify your question with this information.

Comment: @Ted, done. I have explained the term.

Comment: $$L = \{a^nb^mc^md^n \;|\; m,n \geq 1\}\cup \{a^nb^nc^md^m \;|\; m,n \geq 1\}$$. This is an example? see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/inherent-ambiguity-of-the-language-l-2-anbmcm-m-n-geq-1-cup-a

Comment: $$L = \{a^nb^mc^p \;|\; m = n \bigvee m= p \}$$, This is another example.